# Paging not working in category.php

Tags: categories, pagination

Pagination on the category page does not work.

I use a theme called "Bridge", and the permalink is set to "/ blog /% category% /% postname% /".

My category page is in the following url:
http://ikontrol.dk/da/blog/nyheder/
If I use the paging at the bottom, I get the following url:
da/blog/nyheder/page/2/
I give myself and 404 - Page not found.

If I manually change the url to:
da/blog/nyheder/?page=2
Then page 2 is selected, but the content is still page 1.

As I see it in my catgory.php, it calls "get_template_part('templates/blog', 'structure');"

```
<?php 
    global $wp_query;
    global $qode_options_proya;
    global $qode_template_name;
    $id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();

    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
    elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
    else { $paged = 1; }

    if(isset($qode_options_proya['blog_page_range']) && $qode_options_proya['blog_page_range'] != ""){
        $blog_page_range = $qode_options_proya['blog_page_range'];
    } else{
        $blog_page_range = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    }

    $filter = "no";
    if(isset($qode_options_proya['blog_masonry_filter'])){
        $filter = $qode_options_proya['blog_masonry_filter'];
    }

    $blog_style = "1";
    if(isset($qode_options_proya['blog_style'])){
        $blog_style = $qode_options_proya['blog_style'];
    }

    $blog_list = "";
    if($qode_template_name != "") {
        if($qode_template_name == "blog-large-image.php"){
            $blog_list = "blog_large_image";
            $blog_list_class = "blog_large_image";
        }elseif($qode_template_name == "blog-masonry.php") {
            $blog_list = "blog_masonry";
            $blog_list_class = "masonry";
        }elseif($qode_template_name == "blog-masonry-gallery.php"){
            $blog_list = "blog_masonry_gallery";
            $blog_list_class = "masonry_gallery";
        }elseif($qode_template_name == "blog-masonry-full-width.php"){
            $blog_list = "blog_masonry";    
            $blog_list_class = "masonry_full_width";                
        }elseif($qode_template_name == "blog-masonry-date-in-image.php"){
            $blog_list = "blog_masonry_date_in_image";
            $blog_list_class = "masonry blog_masonry_date_in_image";
        }elseif($qode_template_name == "blog-masonry-full-width-date-in-image.php"){
            $blog_list = "blog_masonry_date_in_image";
            $blog_list_class = "masonry_full_width blog_masonry_date_in_image";
        }elseif($qode_template_name == "blog-large-image-whole-post.php"){
            $blog_list = "blog_large_image_whole_post"; 
            $blog_list_class = "blog_large_image";  
        }elseif($qode_template_name == "blog-small-image.php"){
            $blog_list = "blog_small_image";
            $blog_list_class = "blog_small_image";
        }elseif($qode_template_name == "blog-large-image-simple.php"){
            $blog_list = "blog_large_image_simple";
            $blog_list_class = "blog_large_image_simple";
        }elseif($qode_template_name == "blog-large-image-with-dividers.php"){
            $blog_list = "blog_large_image_with_dividers";
            $blog_list_class = "blog_large_image_with_dividers";
        }else{
            $blog_list = "blog_large_image";
            $blog_list_class = "blog_large_image";
        }
    } else{
        if($blog_style=="1"){
            $blog_list = "blog_large_image";
            $blog_list_class = "blog_large_image";
        }elseif($blog_style=="2"){
            $blog_list = "blog_masonry";    
            $blog_list_class = "masonry";   
        }elseif($blog_style=="5"){
            $blog_list = "blog_masonry";    
            $blog_list_class = "masonry_full_width";
        }elseif($blog_style=="3"){
            $blog_list = "blog_large_image_whole_post"; 
            $blog_list_class = "blog_large_image";  
        }elseif($blog_style=="4"){
            $blog_list = "blog_small_image";
            $blog_list_class = "blog_small_image";
        }elseif($blog_style=="6"){
            $blog_list = "blog_large_image_simple";
            $blog_list_class = "blog_large_image_simple";
        }elseif($blog_style=="7"){
            $blog_list = "blog_large_image_with_dividers";
            $blog_list_class = "blog_large_image_with_dividers";
        }elseif($blog_style=="8"){
            $blog_list = "blog_masonry_date_in_image";
            $blog_list_class = "masonry blog_masonry_date_in_image";
        }else {
            $blog_list = "blog_large_image";
            $blog_list_class = "blog_large_image";
        }
    }

    $pagination_masonry = "pagination";
    if(isset($qode_options_proya['pagination_masonry'])){
       $pagination_masonry = $qode_options_proya['pagination_masonry'];
        if(in_array($blog_list, array('blog_masonry','blog_masonry_date_in_image','blog_masonry_gallery'))) {
            $blog_list_class .= " masonry_" . $pagination_masonry;
        }
    }
?>
<?php 
    if(($blog_list == "blog_masonry" || $blog_list == "blog_masonry_date_in_image") && $filter == "yes") { 
        get_template_part('templates/masonry', 'filter');
    }
?>
<div class="blog_holder <?php echo $blog_list_class; ?>">
    <?php
    if(in_array($blog_list, array('blog_masonry','blog_masonry_date_in_image','blog_masonry_gallery'))){ ?>
        <div class="blog_holder_grid_sizer"></div>
        <div class="blog_holder_grid_gutter"></div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if(have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php 
            get_template_part('templates/'.$blog_list, 'loop');
        ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php if($blog_list != "blog_masonry" && $blog_list != "blog_masonry_date_in_image" && $blog_list != "blog_masonry_gallery") { ?>
        <?php if(isset($qode_options_proya['pagination']) && $qode_options_proya['pagination'] != "0") : ?>
            <?php pagination($wp_query->max_num_pages, $blog_page_range, $paged); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php else: //If no posts are present ?>
    <div class="entry">                        
            <p><?php _e('No posts were found.', 'qode'); ?></p>    
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php if(in_array($blog_list, array('blog_masonry','blog_masonry_date_in_image','blog_masonry_gallery'))) {
    if($pagination_masonry == "load_more") { 
        if (get_next_posts_link()) { ?>
            <div class="blog_load_more_button_holder">
                <div class="blog_load_more_button"><span rel="<?php echo $wp_query->max_num_pages; ?>"><?php echo get_next_posts_link(__('Show more', 'qode')); ?></span></div>
                <div class="blog_load_more_button_loading"><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="qbutton"><?php _e('Loading...', 'qode'); ?></a></div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
     <?php } elseif($pagination_masonry == "infinite_scroll") { ?>
        <div class="blog_infinite_scroll_button"><span rel="<?php echo $wp_query->max_num_pages; ?>"><?php echo get_next_posts_link(__('Show more', 'qode')); ?></span></div>
    <?php }else { ?>
        <?php if($qode_options_proya['pagination'] != "0") : ?>
            <?php pagination($wp_query->max_num_pages, $blog_page_range, $paged); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Put below code before HTML

```
$qode_options_proya['pagination'] = 1;
```